# Enviar parâmetro do formulário para o controller através de ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax, json

Tenho uma Index com um formulário, preciso preencher esse formulário e ao clicar no botão Filtrar, chamar o controller usando ajax.

Index.cshtml

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ResultadoPesquisa", "RelatorioDesempenhoData", FormMethod.Post))
 {
     @Html.DisplayName("Item de Contrato")
     @Html.DropDownList("ItemContratoId", String.Empty)
     @Html.DisplayName("Mes")
     @Html.DropDownList("MesId", String.Empty)
     @Html.DisplayName("Ano")
     @Html.DropDownList("AnoId", String.Empty)
     @Html.DisplayName("Ativo")
     @Html.DropDownList("Ativo", new SelectList(new List<string> { "Ativo", "Inativo" }, String.Empty), String.Empty)

     <input type="submit" value="Filtrar" onclick="exibeBarChart(ItemContratoId, IndicadorId, MesId, AnoId, Ativo)"/>
 }
```

Controller.cs

```
public string ResultadoPesquisa(int? ItemContratoId, int? IndicadorId, int? MesId, int? AnoId, string Ativo, string Limpar)
{
    var avaliacaoDesempenho = ad.BuscaFiltrada(ItemContratoId, IndicadorId, MesId, AnoId, Ativo).ToList());

    //...

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

    return json;
}
```

JavaScript.js

```
var json;
function exibeBarChart(ItemContratoId, IndicadorId, MesId, AnoId, Ativo) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/RelatorioDesempenhoData/ResultadoPesquisa',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { ItemContratoId: ItemContratoId, IndicadorId: IndicadorId, MesId: MesId, AnoId: AnoId, Ativo: Ativo },

        success: function (data) {
            json = data;
            var dado = JSON.parse(json);
            //...
        },
        error: function (data) {
            json = "error";
        }
    });
}
```

Acontece que o controller está sendo chamado, mas não pelo Ajax. E ao término da execução do controller, sou redirecionado à uma pagina com o json

Alguma sugestão ou possivel solução?

Grato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, comece trocando o tipo do input que dispara o evento, tente isso:

Primeiro crie a seguinte função javascript:

```
function onClickBotaoFiltrar() {
   var ItemContratoId = $("select[id$='ItemContratoId'] option:selected").val();
   // não encontrei um correspondente do indicador id então vou simplesmente informar 0
   var IndicadorId = 0;
   var MesId = $("select[id$='MesId '] option:selected").val();
   var AnoId = $("select[id$='AnoId'] option:selected").val();
   var Ativo = $("select[id$='Ativo'] option:selected").val();

   exibeBarChart(ItemContratoId, IndicadorId, MesId, AnoId, Ativo)
}
```

Após isso altere o botão para

```
<input type="button" value="Filtrar" onclick="onClickBotaoFiltrar()"/>
```

Espero que isso possa ajuda-lo.

Comment: Obrigado pela rápida resposta Edney, no entanto eu já havia feito a substituição de submit para button. E quando faço isso, nem o controller é chamado.

Comment: Qual o erro apresentado no console do browser quando você utiliza a tag como button?

Comment: Por algum motivo ele está dizendo que IndicadorId não está definido: **Uncaught ReferenceError: IndicadorId is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick**

Comment: @EvandroSilva Entendi, o problema neste caso é que você está passando variáveis que não foram criadas, vou editar o post para que a correção fique mais eficiente.

Comment: @EvandroSilva mes Id não irá fornecer um valor, substitua por **$("select[id$='MesId'] option:selected").val();**, pois está sobrando espaço no seletor.

Comment: Efetuei a correção referente à MesId, realmente era o que eu estava precisando, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Funcionou perfeitamente!